# Nginx and Docker with static html: Proxy pass does not forward to expected route

Tags: docker, nginx

I want to serve static html as a service with Docker and nginx as a reverse proxy (there are also a python backend and mysql container, which I excluded here)

I have got the following `docker-compose` file:

```
version: "3.7"

  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    container_name: frontend
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5000:80"

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Dockerfile for Frontend:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
```

`nginx.conf` in my I do this:

```
server {

    listen 80;

    location /frontend {
        proxy_pass  http://frontend:5000/;
        #proxy_pass  http://frontend:5000; -> also tried this  
    }

}
```

Everything builds fine, but the `proxy_pass` does not work as expected.

Where I can reach my app:

http://localhost:5000/

Desired:

http://localhost/frontend

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The NGINX location should be the root (I imagine there is no `/frontend` web path)

```
location / {
    proxy_pass  http://frontend:5000/;
}
```